# How to Configure properly Shopify App Proxy - CORS Error

Tags: shopify

I need help with Shopify Proxy. I enabled the proxy and set the following values:

```
Subpath prefix: apps

Subpath: my-app-proxy

Proxy URL: https://646111ce.ngrok.io/…/…/pricing-rules/public/app_proxy
```

On app I am using the following url to request data

```
https://mystore.myshopify.com/apps/my-app-proxy?aa=xx
```

But I am still getting CORS error. Any suggestions what the issue could be?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code // configuration i your question instead of a link?

Answer (score 1):

You should never see CORS errors with App Proxy. It is called a Proxy for a reason. Shopify takes care of the call to your endpoint. It looks like you are mistakenly calling the wrong URL.

Your example call would work if you tried the URL:

```
/apps/my-app-proxy
```

And not your full Shopify store name.